# Algorithm to sum the numbers between (and including) p and q

Tags: algorithm, sum

Task:

> Write in pseudocode an algorithm to compute the sum of the numbers BETWEEN (and INCLUDING) *p* and *q*, where *p*, *q* are integers. There is no constraint for *p* and *q* (*p* could be smaller, equal to or greater than *q*).
>
> The algorithm should work for the following cases:
>
> *p* = 5, *q* = 9 => sum = 35
>
> *p* = 7, *q* = 7 => sum = 14
>
> *p* = 12, *q* = 8 => sum = 50

I have to solve this with iteration, not with the arithmetic progression formula, which I already did.
I tried this:

```
begin
    input p, q
    S=0
    i=p
    while i≤q
        S= S+i
        i=i+1
    end while
    while i≥q
        S= S+i
        i=i-1
    end while
    while i=q
        S=q+i
    end while
```

Comment: `for(i=p;i<=q;i++)    ans+=i;`

Comment: `sum the numbers between (and including) p and q` _is_ an algorithm.

Comment: begin
input p, q
S=0
 i=p
while  i≤q
              S= S+i
              i=i+1
end while
while i≥q, 
             S= S+i
            i=i-1
end while
whilw i=q
            S=q+i
end while

Comment: Do you think this should work? Don't be hard on me, I am new in this :)

Comment: You should really try to write something yourself. And then maybe, when you get stuck, ask a much more detailed question here. You are now just asking us to do your homework.

Comment: It's not clear what help you're asking for -- where did you get stuck?

Comment: I wrote in a comment above what is my idea for this task. Could this work?

Comment: You're stuck in figuring out whether your idea works? Did you dry-run it against the example cases?

Comment: I run the example cases only on paper. I am not sure if it is ok to put i<= q and i>= q and then put the i= q condition. I should put only < and > ? But if I don't put smaller/ bigger and equal, the example cases don't work.

Comment: What a crazy/strange thing `p = 7, q = 7 => sum = 14`?

Answer (score 0):

just a for loop starting with p and ending at q or vice versa..update sum each time
code:

```
if(p<q)
{
   for(int i=p;i<=q;i++)
   {
       sum=sum+i;
   }
}
else if(p>q)
{
    for(int i=q;i<=p;i++)
    {
       sum=sum+i;
    }
}
else
{
   sum=2*p;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is the closest to what I had in mind. Initially I thought of this solution: input p, q S=0 i=p while i≤q S= S+i i=i+1 end while while i≥q, S= S+i i=i-1 end while whilw i=q S=q+i end while but yours is more accurate.

Answer (score -3):

Long time back some mathematician invented **Arithmetic progression**, you can use that.

**Sum = N*( First  Term+ Last Term)/2**

```
N = Number of terms i.e q-p+1;
First term = p
Last term = p+ (N-1)
```

Comment: From the question, eight minutes before your non-answer: `not with the arithmetic progression formula`.